# Refresh Power Query For Excel File in OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive, microsoft-powerbi, microsoft-flow

I have a Microsoft Form that saves to an Excel file in my OneDrive. I use Power Queries to manipulate the data. This works fine for when I need open the excel file on my computer and I can then refresh the queries, but when I open in excel online I get "External Data Refresh Failed".
What I would like to do is create a power automate that will automatically refresh the queries and then import them into a database.
I'm new to power automate so any help is much appreciated!
TLDR: I need a power automate to automatically refresh power queries in an excel file located in my OneDrive daily

Comment: This behavior is not available in Excel online, you can refer to this support article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-excel-a42d5c92-dc63-4076-90f2-5ebcc3e5da77

Comment: Try to use Power BI: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-onedrive-business-links
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-connect-to-files-in-app-workspace-onedrive-for-business
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-desktop-file-onedrive

Answer (score 1):

Power Query has been integrated with Flow -> Power Automate for while now.

https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/